# Pydev in Eclipse default working directory

Tags: python, eclipse

What is the default working directory for my project? I have several projects under my workspace, and a couple of run configurations. I use os.getcwd() and the directory goes to other project's folder, after deleting all run configurations, the directory goes to eclipse's install folder. How to make the default working directory goes to my project folder or the \src folder?

EDIT:

In my PYTHONPATH that will be used in the run:

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_1.5.4.2010011921\PySrc\pydev_sitecustomize;
C:\(MyProjectDirecotry)\\src;
C:\Python26;
C:\Python26\DLLs;
C:\Python26\lib;
C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk;
C:\Python26\lib\plat-win;
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages
```

maybe there's `C:\Program Files\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_1.5.4.2010011921\PySrc\pydev_sitecustomize;`  in the first line causing the issue. Why is this happened? How to revert it back to default? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Run Dialog...-> Select your run configuration->Arguments Tab->Working directory:

mine is set to ${workspace_loc}:test/src/ for a project name test i created in my workspace