# Python: wget does not work in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

The following function works when I run it from command line with `python test.py`

```
   def get_pdb(self,pdb):

        import os
        from subprocess import call

        os.chdir('./mobcal_data/PDBs/')
        call(["wget", "http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/2kqx.pdb"])
```

But when I try and run it with eclipse I get the following `OSError`

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I do not understand why it will work when I run the script from the command line and not within eclipse.

Comment: What is `PATH` set to in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think the error might actually be coming from the `os.chdir()` call.

You likely have a different working directory depending on whether you run the script manually or through Eclipse.  Try adding the following line somewhere in the script to check this:

```
print os.getcwd()
```

If this is the issue, you may need to use an absolute path instead of a relative path in the `os.chdir()` call, or change the configuration in Eclipse to start the script in the expected location.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3089474/505154) has some instructions on how to do that.

Comment: I used the code you suggested and the current working directory was changed as I intended it to.

Comment: @Harpal - Try printing `os.environ['PATH']` to see if that is different in Eclipse.