# How do I read a text file in Pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, file-io, pydev

I'm doing a school assignment that requires me to read a file. I chose to use the Eclipse and Pydev combination because I really like the environment. However, no matter where I place the .txt file I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'` I've tried placing it in the src folder and the file directory. Something that I find quite odd is that if I were to run the same python module in IDLE, the file is found and read perfectly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please post your directory structure and code

Comment: You keep asking similar questions - please make some effort and provide longer description of what you do or are trying to do exactly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745875/change-current-work-directory-in-eclipse

Comment: As Chris above stated - paste your dir structures ie. where your code is, where your project is and code that you use to read it - otherwise this will lead us nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot determine where to place your file - place it anywhere and use absolute path:

```
print(open(r'c:\your_file.txt', 'r').read())
```

If you've not played with your eclipse too hard you can just place **your_file.txt** in your project directory and use:

```
print(open('your_file.txt', 'r').read())
```

**Update:**

From one of your comments I've seen that you are doing sth extremely weird - look here:

[image]

You've somehow managed to open ***python.exe*** in your console window within eclipse and you edit files with eclipse but run it from python.exe directly on right hand side hence your code on the left has different environment if executed from eclipse and different when executed from right handside window.

Close that console and push PLAY button in your ECLIPSE: [image]

You better first edit your files in something easier like notepad++. Just create your python source within directory whrer your python.exe resides and run that from command line with:

> python.exe yoursource.py

Once you get a hang of how things work - switch to eclipse.
While working in notepad++ follow [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

**You simply are trying to do too many unknown to you things at the same time - this way you'll be scratching your head all day long**

Comment: How do I get eclipse to look at my project directory rather than the eclipse directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse). Here's an image of my setup: http://imgur.com/aRt09NH

Comment: @wonggr: Makalele has answered you an hour ago - follow the link he has pasted - it contains answer to your comment.

Comment: Thanks mate, helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the file in the same folder as your `.py` file, if that doesn't work try to find out what directory it's currently using `os.getcwd()`.

To fix this specifically:

Open Run Dialog...-> Select your run configuration->Arguments Tab->Working directory

**EDIT:**

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I use os.getcwd()?

Comment: you first import os and the you do print os.getcwd()

Comment: It's printing out C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse so does that mean it is looking there for my file?

Comment: yep, that's where it's currently looking

Comment: I'm changing the Working directory but os.getcwd() is sill giving me the default directory, is there a way to get eclipse to look at src instead?

Comment: Lucas is implying you look at the os module.  It has useful methods for changing directories.  I've upvoted his answer for you.  Look at:    http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os#os

Answer (score 0):

[Pydev in Eclipse default working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089070/pydev-in-eclipse-default-working-directory)

Took me 10 seconds to find ;)

When you run your script from console it's this file directory, but from eclipse it could be another.