# Python detect if code is run on Pydev/Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there some way to detect from within the python code, if the code is being run on Eclipse or using PyDev?

Comment: I don't know your use case, but this is usually a bad idea, ides are designed to run code the same way as you normally would.

Comment: Code run from a IDE has a different relative path for input file compared to a code run directly from the terminal. So I want to use this distinction to appropriately change the path to input file. I want may code to remain same no matter where it is run. So for this path to input file may differ.

Comment: You can usually do that in the ide settings.

Comment: I pass arguments to my code through a parameters file which is further processed by argparse module. So the contents of the parameters file should not change.

Comment: Yes, but you can change the path in the IDE so it matches the one in your terminal.

Comment: How do I change the relative path in PyDev plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089070/pydev-in-eclipse-default-working-directory

Answer (score 1):

This code is what I'm using:

```
    import os
    if 'PYDEV_CONSOLE_ENCODING' not in os.environ:
        main()
    else:
        path = r'C:\Users\Default' 
        main([path, '--db','x:\\out.db3', '--clear'])
```

If ran outside of the Eclipse IDE, my `main` would get arguments from the command line as  no arguments are provided. Otherwise it will use the arguments provided in the 'else' clause and allow me to debug specific cases running pyDev within the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: it did not work for me but it made me look into system variables. for me this worked: if 'PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC' in os.environ: