# Why does Eclipse PyDev not find existing file?

Tags: python, eclipse

When i try to run my python project using PyDev of Eclipse, i get the error message:

```
 File "Bob.py", line 35, in <module>
    with open('ConfigUser\project_config.yml', 'r') as stream_project_config:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ConfigUser\\project_config.yml'
```

- I checked the file exists (I can even navigate to it by clicking the error message)
- Run the same command from console, which works flawless
- Checked Eclipse Path settings of my python project, they seem alright

Code which tries to access the file:

```
with open('ConfigUser\project_config.yml', 'r') as stream_project_config:
    project_config_read = yaml.load(stream_project_config)
    build_variants = project_config_read[1]
    build_instrumentations = project_config_read[4]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the current working directory of your interpreter actually your project root? You can check with [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

Comment: Console give me the acutal path, eclipse gives me my workspace, which is incorrect. Do you know how to enforce a certain path in eclipse?

Comment: You could either use the absolute path to the file in the `open` call, or you could do [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) to the desired wd or try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3089474/4134674), although I don't know if it still works.